# Flutter: Remove Overflow from keyboard TextFormField in a alertDialog

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, overflow, android-softkeyboard

With an alertDialog I want the user to input the name of a new workout they are creating. However the keyboard causes the whole widget to attempt to scroll and causes the overlay. How do I fix this?

TextFormField in a alertDialog
[image: Overlay on alertDialog]

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Workout Title"),
        content: SizedBox(
          height: 110,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                  focusNode: _focusNode,
                  controller: titleController,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(14),
                  ]),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                        child: const Text("CANCEL")),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            if (titleController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                              dayTiles.add(
                                  DayTile(title: titleController.text));
                            }
                          });
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                          saveData();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: const Text("DONE")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Answer (score 3):

The overflow supposed to be coming from scaffold body. Try to make it scrollable like

```dart
 Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
```

Comment: I don't believe that will work for my implementation of this alertDialog. I attempted something similar before but it resulted in the alertDialog shrinking to only the 'Workout Title' as well as traveling to the top of the screen.

Comment: can you test it and then share the feedback?

Comment: The project is large and changing the scaffold now would entail changing multiple widgets who are individually scrollable. I may not entirely understand the use of scaffold though, am I able to return a scaffold as an alertView?

Comment: it would easier for use if you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `Scaffold` in `alertView`. What you need is to have `SingleChildScrollView` as the body of the parent `Scaffold`.

```
class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Demo'),
      ),
      // right here
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          //child,
          //child,
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(context: context, builder: ...);
              },
              child: const Text('Add workout'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Like I said in another comment, I am near the end of my app and I did not know this was a possibility before so I receive.

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.)

Comment: It would be easier if you share the complete code for this screen